# Allow Samba and Podman to rw on same dir

Tags: fedora, selinux

I'm new to SElinux so I don't know much about how to use it. I want to run my Fedora Server using a samba share (already configured and working) and configured a podman container, mounting the same directory. But while SElinux is on, the container cannot access the mounted directory. Turning SElinux off (`setenforce 0`) "solves" that.

So currently I've tried using `public_content_rw_t` on that directory, but still not works.

```
# first try
$ semanage fcontext -a -t samba_share_t "/srv/downloads(/.*)?"
$ restorecon -Rv /srv/downloads

# second try
$ semanage fcontext -m -t public_content_rw_t "/srv/downloads(/.*)?"
$ restorecon -Rv /srv/downloads
```

In both cases, podman container is not able to access the same directory. SElinux is preventing it (logs: `setroubleshoot[1232603]: SELinux is preventing java from write access on the directory /srv/downloads`). For example using: `podman exec -it $CONTAINER ls -l /downloads` (mounted `/srv/downloads:/downloads` with rw).

I want to run my server with SElinux. What do I need to configure, that both processes are able to use the same directory?

Comment: Is this machine running a Samba _server_ or a Samba _client_?

Comment: I'm using samba server.

Comment: You'll have to generate a local policy module, then, as Guser314 suggested in their answer. This is only currently supported by SELinux if your filesystem was mounted as a client from some other SMB server.

Comment: Generating a local policy should be easy. What do you mean by "from some other SMB server"? If I mount the SMB share using my workstation count?

Comment: I'm facing almost exactly the same problem. Were you ever able to find a satisfying solution to this problem? I also tried virt_use_samba as suggested below but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Since new to SELinux there are more tools available to help you figure it out, which I just found this last week. A starting point is [here](https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2017/11/selinux-audit2why-audit2allow-policy-files/). Mainly the audit.log with audit2why and audit2allow. I setenforce to 0, cp /dev/null over audit.log, run failing commands (which succeed in Permissive mode but are still logged in the audit log), then save the log and analyze as in the link above. I used this process over the last few days to create a custom policy for a flask/apache api running python subprocesses. So not a specific answer, but the process should get you to a solution as it did me.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I can take a look and do some investigating.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by enabling the `setsebool -P virt_use_samba` flag. This seems to enable virtualized instances (..and containers..) access to mounted drives.

Old question, but I found this answer in precisely one location on the internet and it would be good to spread it in case it solves more issues.